# Photo upload using rails not working, params[:photo] seems to return nil and original_filename cannot be called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, upload

I have this bit of code in rails:

Controller:

```
def new
  end

  def create
      the_file = params[:upload][:picture]
      @user = User.where("first_name = ?", session[:current_user_id]).first
      @photo = Photo.create(:date_time => DateTime.now, :file_name => the_file.original_filename, :user_id => @user.id)
      directory = "app/assets/images"
      path = File.join(directory, the_file.original_filename)
      File.open(path, "wb") do |f|
          f.write(the_file.read)
      end
      redirect_to "photos/index/" + @user.id.to_s
  end
```

and View:

```
<% if session[:current_user_id] == nil%>
    <p class = "error" >You cannot upload a photo because you are not logged in. Please log in to continue.</p>
  <% else %>
    <p>
    <%= form_tag({action: :create}, multipart: true) do %>
    <%= file_field_tag 'upload[picture]' %>
    <%= submit_tag("Upload") %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Right now, I'm getting a undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass error, probably because the second [:picture] is being called on nil. I've tried almost every variation of the params[:photo][:upload] etc. but it always seems to treat params as nil, or returns a long string (ActionController...something, but original_filename can't be called on it either). Any ideas on what is going on is appreciated! I suspect that the photo isn't actually being uploaded or my parameters are wrong - I just don't know where.

Comment: Is this rails 3 or 4? How are you handling mass assignment?

Comment: This is rails 4. I'm not sure what you mean by mass assignment - that may be the problem at hand.

Comment: Just searched it up - since this is rails 4, it shouldn't be problem right?

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont have the reputation to comment on your post, I am forced to put this in as an answer. I was looking at the examples for the file_field_tag and it made no reference to the syntax that you are using where in the view you use 'upload[picture]' and then try to access it as a hash in the params.  I would try using the following in the view:
     `file_field_tag 'picture'` 
and in the controller use:
    `the_file = params[:picture]`

[here is the link to the reference I mentioned](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html)